# Freeform Table field - dynamic data?

Tags: plugin-freeform, freeform

I am looking at using the Freeform Table field (https://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v4/overview/fields/#table) and it works great. However it only seems to use values for dropdowns that you enter mnaually. What i want to achieve is for a user to select from a list of entries in craft and also select a quantity.

Is there any way to bring in the list of entries dynamically?

Macolm